# WCF Discovery finds endpoint but host is "localhost"

Tags: c#, wcf, service-discovery

I am trying to use the Discovery feature in WCF using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456783(v=VS.100).aspx as a starting point. It works fine on my machine, but then I wanted to run the service on a different machine. The service was discovered properly but the hostname of the found service is always "localhost" which is of course not much use.

### Service Endpoint:

```
var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new UriBuilder { Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeNetTcp, Port = port}.Uri);
var endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IServiceInterface)), new NetTcpBinding (), endpointAddress);
```

### Client:

```
static EndpointAddress FindServiceAddress<T>()
{
  Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
  stopwatch.Start();
  DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
  // Find  endpoints            
  FindResponse findResponse = discoveryClient.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(T)));
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Searched for {0} seconds. Found {1} Endpoint(s).",stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000,findResponse.Endpoints.Count));
  if (findResponse.Endpoints.Count > 0)
  {
     return findResponse.Endpoints[0].Address;
  }
  return null;
 }
```

Should I simply set the Host to System.Environment.MachineName?

Comment: I also have this problem. Assuming its cause the UDP protocol includes the service address... which ultimately comes from the app.config

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After doing some more searchingI have found no other solution than to use the System.Environment.MachineName

```
 new EndpointAddress(new UriBuilder {Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeNetTcp, Port = port, Host = System.Environment.MachineName}.Uri);
```

Answer (score 8):

I spent a lot of time investigating this problem. Building base addresses in the code was not acceptable for me, as it implies hardcoding transport scheme and port (the latter, of course, can be stored in a separate config section, but then why not just to use the existing section?). I wanted to have an ability to just configure the base address in config as usual. And it turns out that a base address like `<add baseAddress="net.tcp://*:8731/"/>` will perfectly work. I think the same is true for programmatic configuration.

Comment: I am assuming that * binds to every available IP address (across all the network adapters)?

Comment: Ultimately yes. To be accurate, when the config is loaded, this uri is parsed, and the '*' character is replaced with a result of the call to Dns.GetHostName(). You can see more if you take a look at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadHostConfig method using Reflector :)